# Can proguard leave out the unused classes of the libraries?

Tags: java, proguard

I have a java application using the pdfbox library, which makes 10mb. I use just a few classes of this library.

I thought that ProGuard would generate a standalone jar for my application. But the jar generated by ProGuard still needs the pdfbox.jar in the /lib folder to run. Am I doing something wrong? How could I achieve my goal? (leaving out the 99% of the library classes I don't use).

**Note after comments**:
- the original jar and its libraries are generated with Netbeans. I first used ProGuard GUI but following the comments I received on this question, I switched to scripting. Same result: the app works only when the libraries are in a /lib folder next to the jar.

The Proguard script:

```
-injars       "C:\Users\C. Levallois\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ZoText\dist\ZoText.jar"
-outjars      "C:\Users\C. Levallois\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ZoText\dist\ZoText_short.jar"

-libraryjars  <java.home>/lib/rt.jar
-libraryjars  "C:\Users\C. Levallois\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ZoText\dist\lib\Boilerpipe_short.jar"
-libraryjars  "C:\Users\C. Levallois\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ZoText\dist\lib\commons-io-2.1.jar"
-libraryjars  "C:\Users\C. Levallois\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ZoText\dist\lib\commons-lang3-3.0.1.jar"
-libraryjars  "C:\Users\C. Levallois\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ZoText\dist\lib\guava-10.0.1.jar"
-libraryjars  "C:\Users\C. Levallois\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ZoText\dist\lib\nekohtml.jar"
-libraryjars  "C:\Users\C. Levallois\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ZoText\dist\lib\pdfbox-app-1.6.0.jar"
-libraryjars  "C:\Users\C. Levallois\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ZoText\dist\lib\xercesImpl.jar"


-printmapping proguard.map

-keep public class proguard.ProGuard {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}

-keepparameternames
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,
                SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod

-keep public class * {
    public protected *;
}

-keepclassmembernames class * {
    java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String);
    java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String, boolean);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}
```

Comment: Proguard would do that. have you tried it? You can also just copy the classes you want and use those.

Comment: I mention Proguard in my question, but after your comment I edited it to clarify. Thx.

Comment: Could you post the relevant part of your script?

Comment: I don't have scripts since it all GUI based. Folowing your comment I edited my question to show the options I selected for shrinking in ProGuard (I basically left the default values).

Comment: I've never used the GUI for Proguard, but I'd guess that the relevant bits are in the input/output tab. As Stephen C suggested though, you might have better luck finding help (and tracking down future problems) if you run it via a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it's too late for you, here is the tool doing exactly you wanted:

The tool [minimize-jar](https://github.com/liweys/minimize-jar/releases/tag/v1.0) removes unused classes and creates a uber jar based on `verbose:class` information. It's only 5KB and has no dependency.

Answer (score 2):

The `-libraryjars` hold code that is assumed to be available to your optimized app at runtime. That is, Proguard does not include them in its output; it merely needs them for reference as it is processing the code in `-injars`.

Take away Proguard for a moment: your original unoptimized JAR doesn't work without this library class either, right? Proguard doesn't change that.

If you want it to be packaged up together in the optimized output it has to be present in the input. You would have to include these extra jars as `-injars`, or JARred up together with the input in the first place in order for them to appear in the output.

But, yes: Proguard can strip out unused classes, including those that you built in from this other library, if you configure it to.

Answer (score 1):

According to my reading of the manual, ProGuard *does* leave out unused classes for the JAR files that it process.  So I suspect that you are not processing the `pdfbox.jar` file; i.e. you just have it on the classpath.

---

I recommend that you run Proguard from a script rather than the GUI.  This will allow you to incorporate the obfuscation step into your main build scripts, version control the scripts and ... show other people the script to get their advice / help.