# Swiping between Fragments without android.support.v4

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I wonder if it is possible to implement swiping between `Fragments` with `ViewPager` without the use of android.support.v4? I'm using android.app. Or is there any other way that this can be done?

Thanks

Comment: if you have the appropriate API level you should use the support library. what is your `minimum_sdk`?

Comment: 14. Can I use that support library for just this thing or do I have to change other stuff too?

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder if it is possible to implement swiping between Fragments with ViewPager without the use of android.support.v4?

If you are looking to use `ViewPager` with native API Level 11 fragments, use `android-support-v13.jar` and its implementation of things like `ViewPager` and `FragmentPagerAdapter`. You will find both [the v4](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) and [the v13](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) versions of `FragmentPagerAdapter` in the documentation.

Or, roll your own subclass of `PagerAdapter` that handles fragments in a way that suits you, along with `android-support-v13.jar` for `ViewPager`.

Comment: Or you can copy the source code of ViewPager and it's adapters to your project and make some minor modifications to make it run without support library. That's what I did when I wrote an app for API level 16+.

Comment: @DoctororDrive: That is not necessary; IMHO, it is also not advisable. Now you have to re-do that work every time they ship a new Android Support package, so you pick up any bug fixes. Since ProGuard will strip out unused stuff from your release builds, you should not be saving much, if any, APK space by creating your own separate set of classes.

Comment: As far as I know proguard can't remove unsed classes from library jars.

Comment: @DoctororDrive: And your proof of this is... what, exactly? Note that the author of ProGuard appears to disagree with you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10992604/115145

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417440/can-proguard-leave-out-the-unused-classes-of-the-libraries

Comment: @DoctororDrive: As Sean Owen points out in an answer on the question you just linked to, "Proguard can strip out unused classes, including those that you built in from this other library, if you configure it to". And StephenC, in the other answer on the question you linked to, wrote "According to my reading of the manual, ProGuard does leave out unused classes for the JAR files that it process."

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29537/discussion-between-doctoror-drive-and-commonsware)

Comment: @DoctororDrive: No, thank you. If you have further questions on the behavior of ProGuard, ask a fresh StackOverflow question on that topic.

Comment: So can I use the package for just this thing, or do I have to change the things when I have used android.app?